# Return different promises from same function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation where I return a promise from a function which becomes part of a `$q.all` array. This works great on page load. My problem is I need to call this function potentially many times after this to update the view with new data.

Here is my working code:

```
var vm = this;
var loadingGames = $q.defer();
var loadingPlayers = $q.defer();

var getGames = function() {
  playersService.getGames({
    playerId: playerId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    vm.games = data;
    loadingGames.resolve();
  });
};

var getPlayers = function() {
  playersService.getPlayers({
    playerId: playerId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    vm.players = data;
    loadingPlayers.resolve();
  });
};

$q.all([loadingGames.promise, loadingPlayers.promise]).then(function() {
  populateOptions(vm.games);
  vm.tableParams.reload();
});

var init = function() {
  getGames();
  getPlayers();
}

init();
```

This does not work for an obvious reason, `loadingGames` was resolved on page load, so I will never get updated data by relying on it:

```
var updateStatus = function() {
  getGames();
  loadingGames.promise.then(function() {
    populateOptions(vm.games);
    vm.tableParams.reload();
  });
};
```

This was my next try, but it does not work either, as I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in the console when I attempt to `updateStatus`:

```
var updateStatus = function() {
  getGames().then(function() {
    populateOptions(vm.games);
    vm.tableParams.reload();
  });
};
```

How can I resolve future promises for `getGames()` so `updateStatus()` receives updated data?

Update: Gave it another shot using a callback, but no dice. The functions within the callback never get called.

```
var updateStatus = function() {
  getGames(function() {
    populateOptions(vm.games);
    vm.tableParams.reload();
  });
};
```

Comment: You need a new `q.defer()` object each time to do what you're describing.

Comment: @Shadowen, the problem with that is the user could trigger `updateStatus` through a button click an unknown number of times. So `var refreshingGames = $q.defer()` for example would be resolved the first time that button is clicked and then useless to me on future clicks.

Comment: So I'm saying you need a new `Deferred` object each time the button is clicked (so you can resolve it again).

Comment: Exactly, but I'm not sure if that's even possible when the number of `Deferred` objects needed is unknown; could be 1, could be 100.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **$q.defer()** in your function, and you should return **promise**. Then, you can easily combine these promises.

I wrote an example, with Service and Controller.

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($q){

    var games = ['zelda', 'mario'];

    var players = ['john', 'Donkey kong'];

    function getGames(){
      return $q(function(resolve){
        resolve(games);
      });
    }

    function getPlayers(){
      return $q(function(resolve){
        resolve(players);
      });
    }

    function addGames(name){
      games.push(name);
    }

    function addPlayers(name){
      players.push(name);
    }

    return {
      getGames: getGames,
      getPlayers: getPlayers,
      addGames: addGames,
      addPlayers: addPlayers
    }

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, $q, Service) {

  var vm = this;

  var getGames = function(){

    var defer = $q.defer();

    Service.getGames().then(function(response){
      defer.resolve(response);
    });
    //Return promise
    return defer.promise;

  }

  var getPlayers = function(){

    var defer = $q.defer();

    Service.getPlayers().then(function(response){
      defer.resolve(response);
    });

    return defer.promise;

  }

  var updateStatus = function() {
    //Add games to simulate change
    Service.addGames('Skyrim');

    getGames().then(function(response){
      //Log games array
      console.log('Data updated !');
      console.log(response);
    });
  };

  var promise1 = Service.getGames();
  var promise2 = Service.getPlayers();

  $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(response){
    var games = response[0];
    var players = response[1];
    console.log('first');
    console.log(games);
    updateStatus();
  });



}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

Now, you `getGames()` and `getPlayers()` functions will return promise.